# Find no of changes in a row of a data frame

Tags: r

I would like run my code through all columns in a row, for every row and find out how many + ve changes and negative changes  are there for every row.

+ve Change means increase in number when compared to previous value (eg: (1,3),(2,3))
-ve Change means decrease in number when compared to previous value (eg: (3,2),(2,1))

sample data:

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Also, add example of your data using `dput()` function (not a picture) and example of code that you have tried (*I would like run my code*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With base r: (I created a sample dataset myself)

```
set.seed(2)
PID <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1,2,3), 40, T), nrow = 4))

PID$poschanges <- colSums(apply(PID, 1, diff) > 0)
PID$negchanges <- colSums(apply(PID, 1, diff) < 0)

PID

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 poschanges negchanges
1  2  1  3  2  2  1  1  1  2   3          3          3
2  3  3  2  2  1  2  2  1  2   1          2          4
3  1  3  3  2  1  3  3  1  3   3          3          3
4  2  1  2  1  2  3  2  3  3   2          4          4
```

Answer (score 1):

With tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- gather(df,k,v,-PID)
inner_join(df1  %>% group_by(PID) %>% summarise(n=sum(as.integer(v>lag(v)),na.rm=TRUE)),
           df1  %>% group_by(PID) %>% summarise(n=sum(as.integer(v<lag(v)),na.rm=TRUE)),by="PID")
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#  PID     n.x   n.y
#  <fct> <int> <int>
#1 abc       4     3
#2 def       2     3
#3 hij       0     0
#4 klm       3     2
```